Unreal Engine requires Xcode to compile shaders for Metal
Unreal Engine requires Xcode to compile shaders for Metal.
To continue, install Xcode and open it to accept the license agreement. If you install Xcode to any location other than Applications/Xcode, also run the xcode-select command-line tool to specify its location.
You run in to this error on the mac on trying to open Unreal Engine.

Opening Terminal
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer

If you have not install xcode
Ref : https://mac.install.guide/commandlinetools/3
